# ExtJS4 splash screen app.js returns error

Tags: javascript, extjs4, styles, undefined, splash-screen

I have a initially long loading app, so I tried making a splash screen. It "almost" works perfectly. I'm getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined` which points to a specific line in my app.js. However, I just can't see what's wrong with it. The splash screen loads fine and fades out fine (almost). What I notice is that it appears the div I created is still there yet you can't see it but it's still masking the body from input.  Here's my app.js:

```js
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

var splashscreen;

Ext.onReady(function () {
    // Start the mask on the body and get a reference to the mask
    splashscreen = Ext.getBody().mask('Dashboard Loading...', 'splashscreen');
    // Add a new class to this mask as we want it to look different from the default.
    splashscreen.addCls('splashscreen');
    // Insert a new div before the loading icon where we can place our logo.
    Ext.DomHelper.insertFirst(Ext.query('.x-mask-msg')[0], {
        cls: 'x-splash-icon'
    });
});

Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', {
    controllers: ['Main'],
    stores: ['Saless', 'ProdGrid002s', 'ProdGrid008s', 'ProdGrid009s', 'Unitcosts', 'Prepaids',
        'Logintakes', 'WasteTickets', 'InventoryFinisheds', 'InventoryRoughs', 'Shipments'],
    name: 'Dash1',
    appFolder: '/html/cgi-dev/millapps/dashboards/Dash1/app',
    launch: function () {
        // Setup a task to fadeOut the splashscreen
        var apptask = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function () {
            // Fade out the body mask
            splashscreen.fadeOut({
                duration: 2000,
                remove: true
            });
            // Fade out the icon and message
            splashscreen.next().fadeOut({
                duration: 2000,
                remove: true,
                listeners: {
                    afteranimate: function () {
                        // Set the body as unmasked after the animation
                        Ext.getBody().unmask();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        // Run the fade after launch.
        apptask.delay(1000);
    },

    autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

my style sheet:

```css
.x-mask.splashscreen {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}
.x-mask-msg.splashscreen,
.x-mask-msg.splashscreen div {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 110px 110px 50px 110px;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position: top center;
}
.x-message-box .x-window-body .x-box-inner {
    min-height: 200px !important; 
}
.x-splash-icon {
    /* Important required due to the loading symbols CSS selector */
    background-image: url('/resources/images/logo.jpg') !important;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The error points to the line of code Ext.getBody().unmask(); which is in the afteranimate function.  I'm stumped.....

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated, but you've got a race condition in that code that made you error hard to reproduce. I've had to delay the `Ext.getBody().unmask()` call to trigger it.

The problem is that your anims are destroying the DOM elements that the unmask method tries to access, because of the `remove: true` options. However, since Ext keeps track of the mask internally, you are indeed required to call `unmask()` to avoid unpredictable behaviors later on.

So the solution is simply to remove the two `remove: true` lines in your anims config, and unmask will take care of disposing of the DOM elements itself.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, and really cheered you took the time to put in a thank comment. But if by chance you see this comment, that would help me growing my e-penis if you'd accept this answer ^^